# wpa_supplicant crashing(?)

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, wireless

I just got my Raspberry Pi B+ together with a WiFi dongle from ThePiHut and am now trying to connect it to my WiFi.

It works, at least sometimes.

After booting the Pi, I do not get an automatic connection, but first have to execute 
`ifup --force wlan0`. Before I do this, the adapter does not even show up in the WPA_GUI.

But this only solves the porblem temporarily. After a short period of time (5-15 Minutes), the connection will drop and the WiFi_GUI says

> could not get status from wpa_supplicant

which I can resolve by doing into the command line again and executing `ifup --force wlan0` once more, before dropping again and so on.

Is there a solution to this? Is it just a screwed up configuration file or something that easy?

Comment: How are you powering the WiFi adapter? Can you test it with a powered hub? Most intermittent failures are power related.

Comment: Its plugged into one of the Pi's USB ports. Its this one: [The Pi Hut USB-WLAN-Adapter für Raspberry Pi](The Pi Hut USB-WLAN-Adapter für Raspberry Pi)

Comment: I would suggest trying it in a powered hub to rule out inadequate power as aa root cause.

Comment: Its this one: [The Pi Hut USB-WLAN-Adapter für Raspberry Pi](http://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B009FA2UYK/ref=oh_aui_detailpage_o05_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1).

I don't have a powered HUB :(

Comment: I have no way of knowing if that will work without a powered hub on your particular Pi.

Comment: no one can know if you screwed your config :) can you add the outputs of `ifconfig`, `lsub` and `cat /etc/network/interfaces` to your post? maybe some lines from syslog can help. sometimes this wifisticks try to be very energy safing and switch to power safing mode. i thing this can be approach to solve your problem.

Comment: Try running `wpa_supplicant` as foreground process with debugging information enabled. Maybe you get a bit more information about what's crashing your connection: `wpa_supplicant -d -i wlan0 -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_suuplicant.conf`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried disabling power management? Type `iwconfig` to determine if power management is on or off for the adapter, then edit `/etc/netowrk/interfaces` and add this line `wireless-power off` but the line for this code appears to change from user to user. See the thread for more:

[Raspberry Pi Forum thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=46569&p=647343)